# Rundeck ssh: Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node:

Tags: docker, ssh, rhel7, rundeck

I'm testing rundeck 3.3.0 from Docker 1.13.1  on a RHEL 7.7

I have the following node:

```
  oc3583155071  keys/local/root     password    
    Operating System    Linux
    ssh-authentication: password 
    sudo-command-enabled:   true 
    sudo-password-storage-path: keys/local/root
```

and these are its key storage:

```
  keys/local

  2 keys
    neslarra  Password
    root      Password             <<<<<<==============

    Storage path: keys/local/root 
    Created: 5:27 pm by: admin
```

I tested the ssh connection from rundeck shell and it works OK:

```
  rundeck@9ce08386edcd:~$ ssh root@oc3583155071
  root@oc3583155071's password: 
  [root@oc3583155071 ~]# uname -n; whoami
  oc3583155071
  root
  [root@oc3583155071 ~]#
```

BUT, when I try to exec a command from the runeck GUI it retunrs this error:

```
  Nodes   oc3583155071
  Recent: uname -n; whoami
   
  >  uname -n; whoami #28 
  Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "oc3583155071". Could not authenticate.
  Execution failed: 28 in project Test1: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [oc3583155071: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "oc3583155071". Could not authenticate. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:oc3583155071)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:oc3583155071)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {oc3583155071=[AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "oc3583155071". Could not authenticate. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:oc3583155071)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:oc3583155071)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=-1}}}}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

Help will be appreciate (a lot!!!).
Nestor.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but I have another node "rhlabtest" with its own key "keys/lab/root" and it works fine.

Comment: Can you share your node definition? seems that some node attributes are missing, check this carefully (it's for rundeck 2.11 but is the same 3.3 principle): https://youtu.be/qOA-kWse22g?t=130 and here a good starting point to set up a SSH password based access: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your ssh target node and set up correctly on the Rundeck's node source, your node definition needs more attributes, I leave these steps to configure from scratch:

1. Make sure that your target ssh config admits password login (enable `PasswordAuthentication yes` on the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` config file and restart the `sshd` service: `systemctl restart sshd`).
2. On the Rundeck side [create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hp7G.jpg) a password key to reference it later in the `resources.xml` file (`ssh-password-storage-path` attribute).
3. On Rundeck side, make sure that you're using a well-configured node [definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-storage). I used the following `resources.xml` content example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
 <node name="remote" description="remote ssh node" osFamily="unix" username="vagrant" hostname="192.168.33.20" ssh-authentication="password" ssh-password-storage-path="keys/sshpasswd" />
</project>
```

4. Test sending any command to your new node, on Rundeck GUI, go to "Commands" (Left menu) and select your node on "Nodes" textbox (using `name: <your-node-name>`) and send any command ("Enter a command" textbox), you must [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FgFb.jpg) the result.

Comment: Hi Megadrive68k... thanks a lot. As you said I set the wrong attribute at node definition: I set sudo-password-storage-path instead of ssh-password-storage-path => I fixed it and now all is fine.